# Legend Key for discrete values in spplot

Tags: r, sp, plot

I have a shapefile with various attributes. I want to plot the shapefile using `spplot'.

I first read the shapefile

```
A <- readOGR('myshapefile.shp')
```

I am using the following command:

```
p <- spplot(A, c('lulc', 'lulc_2', 'lulc_3', 
             'lulc_4', 'lulc_5', 'lulc_6', 'lulc_7'), 
        col.regions=myColors, 
        col='transparent', 
        names.attr = c(1998, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2009, 2014, 2017))
```

[image]

Each of the fields / attributes contains 4 values, say 1, 2, 3, 4 and correspondingly need to be labelled A, B, C, D in the legend, along with the color key. How to achieve this? For example, I have put the image of the legend only.

Small update:

I tried to modify the spplot command to:

```
p <- spplot(A, c('lulc', 'lulc_2', 'lulc_3', 
             'lulc_4', 'lulc_5', 'lulc_6', 'lulc_7'), 
        col.regions=myColors, 
        col='transparent', 
        names.attr = c(1998, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2009, 2014, 2017),
        as.table = T,
        colorkey = list(
          right = list( # see ?levelplot in package trellis, argument colorkey:
            fun = draw.colorkey, 
            args = list(
              key = list(
                at = c(1,2,3,4), # colour breaks
                col = myColors, # colours
                labels = list(
                  at = c(1,2,3,4), 
                  labels = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
                )
              )
            )
          )
        ))
```

Even then this is not working.

(see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.3-1/topics/spplot)

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, can you add the output of `spplot()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I waited for long for an answer to the question I posted. I concluded that perhaps it is a bad idea to use `spplot` for this work. The base plot package in R does the work, but is too lengthy.

```
myColors <- c('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red') 
par(mfrow=c(3,3),mar=c(1,1,3,1))
theColors <- myColors[A$lulc]
plot(A, col = theColors, border = NA,main='1998')
theColors <- myColors[A$lulc_2]
plot(A, col = theColors, border = NA,main='1999')
theColors <- myColors[A$lulc_3]
plot(A, col = theColors, border = NA,main='2002')
theColors <- myColors[A$lulc_4]
plot(A, col = theColors, border = NA,main='2003')
theColors <- myColors[A$lulc_5]
plot(A, col = theColors, border = NA,main='2009')
theColors <- myColors[A$lulc_6]
plot(A, col = theColors, border = NA,main='2014')
theColors <- myColors[A$lulc_7]
plot(A, col = theColors, border = NA,main='2017')
plot.new() 
par(xpd=T)
legend('center',inset = 0,
       legend = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 
       fill=myColors, cex=2, horiz = F)
```